# How to remove commas and brackets when printing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently learning Python and am having issues with one of my assignments.

I currently have a script which contains the following code inside it,

```
secret = (first[0].lower(), last[0], "**", "A", cost_A, "**", "B", cost_B, "**", numobox, "**", randint(0, numobox), "**")
if len(secret) % 2 == 0:
    oddeven = ("Even")
else:
    oddeven = ("Odd")



print (secret,oddeven)
```

I am suppose to print out a secret code however when I do it I get an output of

```
('ew', '**', 'A', 2.0, '**', 'B', 1.5, '**', 1, '**', 0, '**') Even
```

What I am trying to get instead would be eW ** A2 ** B1.5 ** 1 ** 0 ** Even

However, I cannot figure out how to do this. I am currently running Python 3.6.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `print(' '.join(secret), oddeven)`

Answer (score 1):

instead of printing the tuples directly you can use join
suppose

```
secret = ('ew', 'A', 2.0, 'B', 1.5,  1,  0 )
print(' ** '.join(map(str,secret)))
```

result is like 
ew ** A ** 2.0 ** B ** 1.5 ** 1 ** 0

you can use anything in place '**' to join it can be anything even empty string like ''.

Answer (score 0):

You could unpack your tuple using a `*`:

```
print(*secret, oddeven)
```

*Side note*: A better way to check your condition is to reverse it:

```
if len(secret) % 2: 
    oddeven = 'Odd'
else: 
    oddeven = 'Even'
```

And you don't need paranthesis around string simply because it works without.